# AWS S3 storage permission denied from Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, permission-denied

I'm trying to access to one of my S3 storage buckets from my EC2 instance deployed by ElasticBeanstalk. My EC2 instance belongs to **aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role** and I have granted this role with **AmazonS3FullAccess** policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then the bucket policy is as follows:

```
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "eb-ad78f54a-f239-4c90-adda-49e5f56cb51e",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXX:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-us-east-XXXXXX/resources/environments/logs/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "eb-af163bf3-d27b-4712-b795-d1e33e331ca4",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXX:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-XXXXXX",
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-XXXXXX/resources/environments/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "eb-58950a8c-feb6-11e2-89e0-0800277d041b",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:DeleteBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-XXXXXX"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to access the bucket from an SSH connection or through a script inside .ebextensions I receive an Access Denied 403 error. I tried making the files public and using the same commands and I worked perfectly, but the files I need can't be public.

I think I have the correct policies for both the bucket and the EC2 role. I might be forgetting some detail though.

Any help will be welcomed. Thank you folks in advance!

Comment: Exactly which key inside the bucket are you trying to access? What happens if you fire up a separate EC2 box with the role and hit stuff from the command line?

Comment: @PhilipKendall I've just tried what you told me. I have fired up a EC2 instance with the role and when I  do the command `aws s3 ls s3:///s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-XXXX/` it returns me the same error. I have tried with other bucket's keys and I received the same. The key I'm trying to access in the bucket is /api/passport. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So based on my knowledge and previous issues I experienced, your bucket policy is incorrect.
It isn't valid because ListBucket and ListBucketVersions actions must be applied to bucket name, not prefix.

Here is my corrected policy that should work;

```
    {   
        "Version": "2008-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "eb-ad78f54a-f239-4c90-adda-49e5f56cb51e",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXX:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
                },
                "Action": "s3:PutObject",
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-us-east-XXXXXX/resources/environments/logs/*",
                    "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-us-east-XXXXXX/resources/environments/logs"
                ]
            },
            {
                "Sid": "eb-af163bf3-d27b-4712-b795-d1e33e331ca4",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXX:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
                },
                "Action": [
                    "s3:GetObject",
                    "s3:GetObjectVersion"
                ],
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-XXXXXX/resources/environments",
                    "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-XXXXXX/resources/environments/*"
                ]
            },
            {
                "Sid": "eb-af163bf3-d27b-4712-b795-anything",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXX:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
                },
                "Action": [
                    "s3:ListBucket",
                    "s3:ListBucketVersions"
                ],
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-XXXXXX"
                ]
            },
            {
                "Sid": "eb-58950a8c-feb6-11e2-89e0-0800277d041b",
                "Effect": "Deny",
                "Principal": {
                    "AWS": "*"
                },
                "Action": "s3:DeleteBucket",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-XXXXXX"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Useful docs to reference to for the future -> [AWS s3 docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html#using-with-s3-actions-related-to-buckets)