# AWS Beanstalk GHCR

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a Docker image hosted in GitHub Container Repository (GHCR) and I'm trying to deploy it to AWS Beanstalk. I've gone through several of their guides and documentation, but my deployment still doesn't seem to work.

I created a `.dockercfg` file using docker login as outlined in the GitHub [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-container-registry) as-well as the AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html). This gave me a `.dockercfg` like the following

```json
{
    "auths": {
        "ghcr.io": {
            "auth": "..."
        }
    }
}
```

I then uploaded this `.dockercfg` file to an AWS S3 bucket and created an access role allowing that file to be read.

(I have the Service Role of my beanstalk environment set to this newly created S3 access role)

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxxx/.dockercfg"
        }
    ]
}
```

After doing this, I created a `Dockerrun.aws.json` file to get the Docker image from GHCR and run on Beanstalk.

```json
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
    "Image": {
        "Name": "ghcr.io/xxxx/xxxx:latest",
        "Update": "true"
    },
    "Authentication": {
        "Bucket": "xxxxx",
        "Key": ".dockercfg"
    },
    "Ports": [
        {
            "ContainerPort": "8000"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, when deploying the application AWS says that the verification has failed and the image cannot be downloaded. I get the following logs in the `eb-engine.log` file

```
2022/12/07 21:53:55.683691 [INFO] start build docker app
2022/12/07 21:53:55.683730 [INFO] generate dockerfile with the image and ports from Dockerrun.aws.json
2022/12/07 21:53:55.683735 [INFO] fetching image and ports
2022/12/07 21:53:55.685173 [INFO] fetching image names from Dockerfile /var/app/staging/Dockerfile
2022/12/07 21:53:55.685259 [INFO] found images [ghcr.io/xxxx/xxx:latest] in Dockerfile /var/app/staging/Dockerfile
2022/12/07 21:53:55.685274 [INFO] download auth credentials for private repo
2022/12/07 21:53:55.685301 [INFO] Downloading: bucket: xxxx, object: /.dockercfg
2022/12/07 21:53:55.714223 [INFO] Download successful0bytes downloaded
2022/12/07 21:53:55.714248 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Docker Specific Build Application]. Stop running the command. Error: AccessDenied: Access Denied
    status code: 403, request id: xxxx, host id: xxxx
2022/12/07 21:53:55.714253 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2022/12/07 21:53:55.714350 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1670450035714,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}
```

I assume this means that Beanstalk is having trouble getting the file from S3, but I can't seem to figure out which part is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the unhelpful "Download successful" message, the error here did actually turn out to be an IAM permission error.

I added the following permissions to the s3 bucket policy:

```json
{
  "Sid": "...",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
  },
  "Action": [
    "s3:ListBucket",
    "s3:ListBucketVersions",
    "s3:GetObject",
    "s3:GetObjectVersion"
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::xxxx",
  ]
},
```

A similar issue and solution was presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54830678/aws-s3-storage-permission-denied-from-elastic-beanstalk).